# Using an existing web service for an Alexa Skill

Tags: api, alexa-skills-kit

I have recently purchased an Amazon Echo Dot and I'm looking into creating a custom skill for it.

I have a web service already which can be used by any client, whether mobile, desktop or web which I want the Echo to be able to utilise as well by posting to and process the response and return the result back to the user.

The only thing I can find is creating an Alexa Web Service but from what I can see it is only allowed to be accessed by Echo nothing else and has to follow certain security items such as requiring Amazon certificates.

It seems a little overkill to create a web service to just wrap my own web service within it, is this the only way, or is there a way I can POST/GET to my own web service process the result and then return the result in a way that is appropriate for the echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, yes, you can point your Alexa skill at any web service but it must conform to Amazon's certificate and port requirements, as well as implementing the ASK interface.

You could point your Alexa skill at an AWS Lambda (it has built-in option for that) and then proxy the request to your existing service but I think that falls into the same category as your "wrap your existing web service in an ASK web service' option though it is a little easier to setup.

On the whole though, I would say that adapting your existing web service to the ASK interface and implementing new functionality needed by an ASK skill will be more work then addressing this issue.

IMO, you might as well create a wrapper service (or lambda) because then you could put the rest of your ASK handling there and not have to mess up your existing, working service.